# How to set up django to send out emails from local MTA?

Tags: django, email, postfix-mta

I am trying to connect to postfix on localhost to send user activation emails. Here is the email settings in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Domain <noreplay@example.com>'
```

However each time, when user tries to register, gets this error:

```
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Why could be wrong here and how to set up django to send out emails from localhost using a MTA like postfix?

Comment: why port 1025? should be 25 if postfix/sendmail is running

Comment: `EMAIL_HOST=localhost` ? are you sure your current server is an smtp server ?

Comment: @warath-coder You spotted it! just changing the port to 25 solved my problem. You answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: @karthikr Yep. I have postfix up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change port to 25 if postfix/sendmail is running on localhost